# Storing and calculating extremely large/small numbers in C# using a Scientific Notation struct

Tags: c#, unity3d

I've been working on an incremental game that I will need to store extremely large scientific numbers. as a part of this game, precision is only important for numbers within similar magnitudes. If a number is 10^20 times larger than another one, then adding or subtracting these numbers has a "negligible" impact on the overall value.

I've built a struct that can be used to represent these impressively massive numbers. ScienceNums can represent a number up to a magnitude of **10^2,147,483,647** or as small as **10^-2,147,483,647**. These numbers can be made further precise and further scaled by using doubles in place of floats, and bigger integers like Int64.

In order for this struct to do more than just store data, I overrode the standard operators for +,-,/,* and implemented them using this struct. Unfortunately, these are not totally lossless operations. Addition and subtractions are ignored for magnitude differences greater than 10^8. Multiplication and division do not ignore any operations, but do run the risk of losing some floating point precision. For most applications (like an incremental game that scales into massive numbers), this shouldn't impact the functionality at all.

There is a Conversion() method that converts numbers back to a float. This is primarily used when a division results in a reasonably sized number and needs to be used for game logic (like HP%, for example).

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

namespace BigNums
{
    [Serializable]
    public struct ScienceNum
    {
        //Should always be between 1 and 9.9999
        public float baseValue;
        public int eFactor;

        public static ScienceNum operator +(ScienceNum sn1, ScienceNum sn2)
        {
            //Bring the 2 numbers to the same power of 10.
            int factorDiff = sn1.eFactor - sn2.eFactor;
            //arbitrary limit, but if the difference in factors is more than 10^8, ignore the operation
            if (factorDiff >= 8)
                return sn1;

            sn2.baseValue /= Mathf.Pow(10, factorDiff);
            sn2.eFactor += factorDiff;

            //Add
            sn1.baseValue += sn2.baseValue;

            //If 0, then 0 can be returned now to avoid div/0 errors
            if(sn1.baseValue == 0)
                return sn1;

            //Convert resulting baseValue back to single digit range
            int eChange = Mathf.FloorToInt(Mathf.Log10(Mathf.Abs(sn1.baseValue)));
            sn1.baseValue /= Mathf.Pow(10, eChange);
            sn1.eFactor += eChange;
            return sn1;            
        }

        public static ScienceNum operator -(ScienceNum sn1, ScienceNum sn2)
        {
            //Bring the 2 numbers to the same power of 10.
            int factorDiff = sn1.eFactor - sn2.eFactor; //1
            //arbitrary limit, but if the difference in factors is more than 10^8, ignore the operation.
            if (factorDiff >= 8)
                return sn1;
            sn2.baseValue /= Mathf.Pow(10,factorDiff);
            sn2.eFactor += factorDiff;

            //Subtract
            sn1.baseValue -= sn2.baseValue;

            //If 0, then 0 can be returned now to avoid div/0 errors
            if (sn1.baseValue == 0)
                return sn1;

            //Convert resulting baseValue back to single digit range
            int eChange = Mathf.FloorToInt(Mathf.Log10(Mathf.Abs(sn1.baseValue)));
            sn1.baseValue /= Mathf.Pow(10, eChange);
            sn1.eFactor += eChange;
            return sn1;
        }

        public static ScienceNum operator *(ScienceNum sn1, ScienceNum sn2)
        {
            sn1.baseValue *= sn2.baseValue;
            sn1.eFactor += sn2.eFactor;

            if (sn1.baseValue >= 10f)
            {
                sn1.eFactor += 1;
                sn1.baseValue /= 10;
            }

            return sn1;
        }

        public static ScienceNum operator /(ScienceNum sn1, ScienceNum sn2)
        {

            sn1.baseValue /= sn2.baseValue;
            sn1.eFactor -= sn2.eFactor;

            if (sn1.baseValue < 1f)
            {
                sn1.eFactor -= 1;
                sn1.baseValue *= 10;
            }

            return sn1;
        }

        public float Conversion()
        {
            return baseValue * Mathf.Pow(10, eFactor);
        }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return String.Format("{0}e{1}", baseValue, eFactor);
        }

        public static ScienceNum FromString(string str)
        {
            ScienceNum scienceNum = new ScienceNum();
            var split = str.Split('e');
            scienceNum.baseValue = Convert.ToSingle(split[0]);
            scienceNum.eFactor = Convert.ToInt32(split[1]);
            return scienceNum;
        }
    }
}
```

The following are my questions:

- The ToString and FromString are for storing these numbers to a database. **Is there a more efficient way to store these?**
- **Are there additional risks to the above logic aside from loss of precision?**
- **Is a performant way to perform square root/power functions using these numbers?**

Comment: For + and -, behavior is asymmetric: you handle the case where `sn1` is much greater than `sn2`, but not the other way around. As a consequence, `a + b != b + a`, which can lead to subtle problems.

Comment: Thank you @Aganju ! I completely overlooked that. Please consider writing that as a formal answer so that I may award a vote to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In [Scientific notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_notation) your `baseValue` is called `coefficient` while `eFactor` is called `exponent`. You should use the conventional naming.

---

I would definitely make the type immutable in order to make it behave like any other numerical type - as a constant/literal. It will avoid misunderstandings and minimize errors:

You could define it like:

```
  [Serializable]
  public struct ScienceNum
  {
    //Should always be between 1 and 9.9999
    private readonly float coefficient;
    private readonly int exponent;

    public ScienceNum(float coefficient, int exponent)
    {
      this.coefficient = coefficient;
      this.exponent = exponent;
    }

    public float Coefficient => coefficient;
    public int Exponent => exponent;

    // ...
  }
```

You'll then have to modify your operator implementations so they don't make the calculations on the fields of the arguments.

---

> ```
>     //Should always be between 1 and 9.9999
>     public float baseValue;
> ```

You should protect against overflow of the coefficient (baseValue) in the constructor:

```
public ScienceNum(float coefficient, int exponent)
{
  if (coefficient < 1f || coefficient > 9.9999f) throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(coefficient));

  this.coefficient = coefficient;
  this.exponent = exponent;
}
```

---

It would be convenient if you implement cast operators for the primitive numerical types (int, float, long, double etc.)

Answer (score 3):

Not a full review, but a relevant point:
For + and -, behavior is asymmetric: you handle the case where `sn1` is much greater than `sn2`, but not the other way around. As a consequence, `a + b != b + a`, which can lead to subtle problems.